# PHP: Run function for a variable in another function

Tags: php, function, class, variables

I wanna print it to:

> abcblabla

```
function r($data){
    strtolower($data);
}

function x($print){
    echo "abc".r($print);
}

x("BLABLA");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `return` in your `r()` function.

```
function r($data){
   return strtolower($data);
}

function x($print){
echo "abc".r($print);
}

x("BLABLA");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `r()` function needs to return the data. You do this by using the `return` statement.

```
function r($data){
   return strtolower($data);
}
```

More info on return can be found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to return the variable ,you forget to return